# Writing a single sequence from a file in FASTA format

Tags: bash, bioinformatics, fasta

Given a file in FASTA format (your.file), for example:

```
>Code1234_length1
ABCEDLKSDJFABCEDLKSDJFABCEDLKSDJFABCEDLKSDJFABCEDLKSDJF
>Code1335_length2
AJDHIEUNAJDHIEUNAJDHIEUNAJDHIEUNAJDHIEUNAJDHIEUN
```

But the content after `>Code1234_length1` is unknown (in this example it was known just for a reproducible sample).
I would like to get the unknown contents after `>Code1234_length1`, including the string `>Code1234_length1` but before the next `>` and output it in a new file.
i.e.

```
>Code1234_length1
ABCEDLKSDJFABCEDLKSDJFABCEDLKSDJFABCEDLKSDJFABCEDLKSDJF
```

How could this be done? Thank you.

Comment: What do you know about the contents of the second line? For example, can it start with `>`? Also, are you just looking for the line after `>Code1234_length1` or do you want to split the file into each of its parts (each `>Code****` and the following line)?

Comment: No, I do not know the contents of the second line, it does not start with ```>```. I just know that it would be before another ```>```. I am just looking for the (many) lines after ```>Code1234_length1``` and to put the outputs into a new file.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If `awk` is your option, would you please try:

```
awk '
    /^>Code1234_length1/ {f = 1; print; next}   # if the keyword is found, set the flag,
                                                #    print the line and continue with the next line
    f {                                         # if the flag is set
        if (/^>/) f = 0                         #    if next ">" is found, reset the flag
        else print                              #    otherwise print the line
    }
' your.file > new.file
```

It works even if multiple lines follow the `>Code1234_length1` line.

Answer (score 2):

These are sequences in FASTA format. Do not reinvent the wheel. In particular, do not write yet another FASTA parser. Instead, use any of the customized bioinformatics tools/libraries for processing them.

For example, use `seqtk` as a command-line tool (or `BioPython`, `BioPerl`, etc as libraries for the corresponding languages):

lh3/seqtk: Toolkit for processing sequences in FASTA/Q formats: https://github.com/lh3/seqtk

> Extract sequences with names in file name.lst, one sequence name per
> line:
>
> ```
> seqtk subseq in.fq name.lst > out.fq
> ```

To install `seqtk`, you can use, for example, `conda` like so:

```
conda create -n seqtk seqtk
```

Example:

```
cat > your.fasta <<EOF
>Code1234_length1
ABCEDLKSDJFABCEDLKSDJFABCEDLKSDJFABCEDLKSDJFABCEDLKSDJF
>Code1335_length2
AJDHIEUNAJDHIEUNAJDHIEUNAJDHIEUNAJDHIEUNAJDHIEUN
EOF

echo 'Code1234_length1' > name.lst

seqtk subseq your.fasta name.lst > out.fasta
```

Output:

```
>Code1234_length1
ABCEDLKSDJFABCEDLKSDJFABCEDLKSDJFABCEDLKSDJFABCEDLKSDJF
```

Answer (score 0):

Try this:

```
$ csplit -z test.txt '/^>/' '{*}'
```

Example:

```
$ cat test.txt
>Code1234_length1
ABCEDLKSDJFABCEDLKSDJFABCEDLKSDJFABCEDLKSDJFABCEDLKSDJF
>Code1335_length2
AJDHIEUNAJDHIEUNAJDHIEUNAJDHIEUNAJDHIEUNAJDHIEUN

$ csplit -z test.txt '/^>/1' '{*}'
18
74
49

$ ls -1
test.txt
xx00
xx01

$ cat xx00
>Code1234_length1
ABCEDLKSDJFABCEDLKSDJFABCEDLKSDJFABCEDLKSDJFABCEDLKSDJF

$ cat xx01
>Code1335_length2
AJDHIEUNAJDHIEUNAJDHIEUNAJDHIEUNAJDHIEUNAJDHIEUN
```

Answer (score 0):

Simple awk:

```
awk 'BEGIN {RS=">"} $0 ~ /Code1335_length2/ { print ">"$0 }' file
```

Set the record separator to ">" and then search for the Code string required (without the proceeding ">") When we find a match, print the record ($0) along with a proceeding ">"